# How can I define an array constant?

Tags: php, arrays, constants

When I try to define an array as constant there is a `warning! The constant must be a scalar value`. But how I can define an array that I cann't modify next in my script? Any solutions?

Comment: It does not really need!... Define a function and return your array. So call the function when needed.

Comment: There is also good solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can not do this, so you can use some tricks:

One of the way is using `serialize`(also you can use implode/explode, json_encode/json_decode):

```
define ("MyArray", serialize (array ("first", "second", "third")));
```

And after that :

```
$MyArray = unserialize (MyArray); //here your array again
```

Another way is use class, in which you will have `private static` variable

```
class arrayConstant{
    private static $myArray=array ("first", "second", "third"); //here you set your array
    public static function getmyArray() {
        return self::$myArray; //return array
    }
}
$arrayConstant = arrayConstant::getArray(); //getting the array
```

Comment: Cool, it's a nice solutions, I like it! Thanks

Comment: I think about a class with `private` properties, but solution without OOP also very nice :)

Comment: Epp, it is one of possible ways)

Comment: `define ("MyArray", serialize (array ("first", "second", "third")));` What is this? @sergio please explain, how  and where you can using this code?

Comment: @voodoo417 There is explain: `$MyArray = unserialize (MyArray);` - for my aims it work.

Comment: @voodoo417 It just as example, hot to make array const

Comment: @Victor show ,please, small  example, how you would use code

Comment: @voodoo417 For example: `in_array('first', unserialize(MyArray));`

Comment: @Victor Sorry, I asked about a real example where it can be used. I don`t understand this approach.

Comment: `if (in_array('first', unserialize(MyArray)) ) { die('Reserved keyword accured!'); }` - this is a real example. And I cann't modify array, what I exactly want. I think it's a simple

Comment: @Victor Ok, i understood u )